# Should one test tests?

Tags: testing

I study computer science and I was taught that sometimes one can test tests. The lecturer did not used citations. One other programmer told that this is not useful. Is there any research showing pros and cons of testing tests?

Comment: (Reads SE more than CS.)

Comment: @greybeard: And already asked and answered there: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/11485/1352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes you mean write automated tests for your automated tests.

In practice, this is not done. In fact, in the work place, people joke about testing the tests. However, if your tests utilize a modular piece of code that can use some testing, then write some unit tests for it. In this scenario, you are not really testing the tests, but you are testing a piece of code that is utilized in testing. So, no, don't test your tests because then you might need to write tests to test the tests that test your tests.

One obvious con about testing the tests is that you're wasting time writing more tests when time is already tight because you're in a 2 week sprint. Now, that you have tests to test the tests, you need to maintain that code too, so another con is created where you have to maintain your test code and maintain your tests that test the tests code, which just wastes more time.

**EDIT**

A software developer should not be testing tests. The tests are written to test the code the software developer is creating. The following will be useful for you:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/how-to-test-the-tests

Answer (score 0):

In practice that happens as soon as the software you are testing is good enough (during development) that it should pass the test, and the test declares failure. At that point you know that software or test are faulty and find the fault.

And if I want to make sure your test detects faults in my software, then I will add a fault, check that the test fails, add a different fault etc. So as the software developer I may very well test your test.